# Rspec hangs when testing for a 401 error with no records found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rails-api

I'm running an integration test using RSpec on a Rails 4 API running rails-api. I want to see that if the wrong email address is passed to the login controller I get a 401 back.

Here is my expectation

```
it "should throw invalid login for user with invalid email" do
  post "/api/v1/users/sign_in", uname: "wrong_email@wrong.com", password: "12234"

  expect(response).to eq(401)

end
```

In my controller I have:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:uname])
  if(@user && @user.valid_password?(params[:password]))
  ....
end
```

This works fine in the browser and I get a 401 back. But when I run rspec it will just hang and never report failure or pass, just sit there with no error. The crux of the problem appears to be the if(@user) part. If I remove that then the test will at least run.

I checked log/test.log and I can see **Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)** in the log.

**Update**

To clarify, this is a `request spec`. I'm testing that the consumer of the API would receive a 401 response in the case of an invalid email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 expect(response.response_code).to eq 401
```

or

```
 expect(response.status).to eq 401
```

Comment: That did it. `expect(response.response_code).to eq 401` worked. What threw me is that for 200 responses I have been using `expect(response).to be_success` but clearly for non-200 responses I need to be more specific.